# How to manage events in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, session, events, listener, provider

I'm trying to manage session/events with Laravel but i'm not sure to really understand.

I have an object with an expiration date stored in my database. I would like to change his state when the current time is equal to the expiration date. Do I have to use listener/events or sessions variables or something else ?

Same problem with my cart. I would like to empty the cart after 15min of inactivity (i am using Crinsane Cart).

Any ideas ?

Regards,

Jeremy

Comment: Chances are you probably want a cron for the first thing. Regarding emptying the cart, not sure why you would want this however you could wrap a middleware around the routes that checks if the last activity of the cart is > (time - (60*15))

Answer (score 0):

You can create [scheduled task](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling) for that. Check all records that are expired and update the status:

```
Model::where('status', 0)
     ->where('expiration_date', '<', Carbon::now())
     ->update(['status' => 1]);
```

Then add the task. For example, if you want to run this task every minute:

```
$schedule->command(status:update)->everyMinute();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response. It should be work perfectly. But if I want to detect the state's change automatically, is it possible ? Because running a task every minutes could be heavy ?

Comment: @JérémyAublanc you can't do this automatically. What you can do is do the check with every request, but running scheduled task is so much better.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem which could easily be dealt with by using [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling) of Laravel itself.

You would need two jobs:

- The first needs to be fired every day (I assume) and run a query to select all objects where the experiation date is expired. (See the answer of Alexey for the query)
- The second needs to check wether a cart has been inactive for more than 15 minutes and delete it if it is like so:

`Cart::where('updated_at, '<', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(15))->delete();`

Comment: For the cart case, are you sure I can do that? Because the "timer" should be runned when the user add his first item and being empty after 15min of unpaid cart. Is it not better to use session variable (store for each user). I am really confuse with this case ...

Comment: Maybe using event saying 'I just add an item in my cart .. ' ?

Comment: It depends on what kind of behaviour you want to create on your website. Do you want to remove a cart that has been inactive for a long time or when the user shops to long? If I where you I would run a daily query that removes carts that are older than 24 hours, so that you never delete a cart that is used by a user at that moment.

Comment: I would like to give only 15min to order before expiring the cart because I sell limited products. I don't want to allow users to keep items in their cart for too long. you know what I mean ?

Comment: The only thing I can come up with is logging when the user connected to the cart was last active (like loading a new page, which you could store with the cart in the database in a field called something like last_activity_at). Next I would create a Task that runs every minute and selects the carts where the value for last_activity_at is more than 15 minutes ago and deletes them. I believe this is the most quick and clean solution.